# JQuery Ajax Request returning error on android

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I'm facing an error trying to execute requests using Android. When on PC browser, everything works fine, but on Android I can't get a response. My errors return are 
Status: "Error" and thrownException empty.

I'm trying to execute it in android 8.0 and 5.0 using chrome 70

This is my code:

```
    function abc(url, myFunction){
    $.support.cors = true;
    $.allowCrossDomainPages = true;
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        dataType: 'html',
        cache: false,
        crossDomain: true,
        success: function(html){
            myFunction(html);
            alert(String(JSON.stringify(html)));
        },
            error: function(html, a, b){  
            alert("obj: " + html + "\n" + "Status: " + a  + "\n" + "Error: " +b);
        }
    });
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: connect your phone to a os with chrome and open dev tools to see if you have any console errors

Comment: What jQuery version are you using? Because I remember getting some inconsistencies using jQuery v3.x  between my Android phone (v4.x) and my Desktop PC